# How do you use an Event, given only a name string supplied in xaml?

Tags: wpf, xaml, events, mvvm

I've seen in triggers, attached properties, and behaviors the ability to specify `SourceObject="myButton" EventName="Click"` -- what I want to know is how do you access the event, given its name and owner object, in code? Does this require reflection to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you use reflection:

```
var instance = new SomeClassType();
var method = "MyEvent";

var handler = instance.GetType().GetMethod(method);
handler.Invoke(instance, null);
```